# PythonAnywhere - OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonanywhere, aiogram

this code for a telegram bot was working previously on pythonanywhere until someone took it down accidentally, now trying to upload it again but facing some errors. ive tried turning off my firewall to fix the error but im not very well versed in python so not sure if theres something missing in the code or its completely a network issue, for which i also dont know how to fix. this is the bot.

```
`# bot
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

# datetime
import datetime

# web browser
import webbrowser

# string manipulation
import re

# logging
import logging

BOT_TOKEN = 'XXXXX'

bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN)

# dispatch bot
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
 
def app_run():
    """
    Prepares environment to start the bot
    """
    executor.start_polling(dp, 
                            timeout=30, 
                            skip_updates=True, 
                            on_startup=logger.info('Starting environment...'),
                            on_shutdown=print(' Program started successfully'))

def setup_applevel_logger(filename):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # filename
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(f"{filename}.log")
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    
    return logger

def get_keyboard():
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row(button1)
    markup.row(button2)
    markup.row(button3, button4)
    return markup

# button functions
button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Apply via Whatsapp ', callback_data='apply_via_whatsapp')
button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Apply with Portfolio ', callback_data='apply_via_portfolio')
button3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Post a Job ‍', callback_data='post_job')
button4 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Visit our Website ', callback_data='visit_website')

# keyboard_inline = InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(button1, button2, button3, button4)
keyboard_inline = get_keyboard()
    
#! function after this line can be called by BOTH admins and users

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(f' Version Launch 1.0 is online as of {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")}')

@dp.channel_post_handler()
async def channel_post(message: types.Message):
    """
    Handles all channel posts

    Args:
        message (types.Message): Any channel post (in text format)
    """
    global job_id
    
    if re.search(r'Job ID: [A-Z]+[0-9]+', message['text']):
        job_id = re.findall(r'Job ID: [A-Z]+[0-9]+', message['text'])[0].split()[2]
    else:
        job_id = None
    await message.delete()
    await message.answer(f"{message['text']}", reply_markup=keyboard_inline)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text=['apply_via_whatsapp', 'apply_via_portfolio', 'post_job', 'visit_website'])
async def inline_buttons(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    """
    Callback function for button 

    Args:
        call (types.CallbackQuery): Distributes function to button press
    """    
    if call.data == 'apply_via_whatsapp':
        # opens whatsapp with job code/title of the message
        global job_id
        webbrowser.open_new(f'https://wa.me/6596963689?text={job_id}')
    elif call.data == 'apply_via_portfolio':
        # opens telegram @jojoweipop with the text "name, age, experience and address"
        text = 'Name%3A%0AAge%3A%0ANationality%3A%0APast%20Experience%3A%0APlease%20send%20a%20photo%20of%20yourself%20too'
        webbrowser.open_new(f'https://wa.me/6596963689?text={text}')
    elif call.data == 'post_job':
        # opens telegram @jojoweipop with message ‘hi would like to post a job’
        text = "Hi%20would%20like%20to%20post%20a%20job%0ACompany%20name%3A%0AJob%20details%3A"
        webbrowser.open_new(f'https://wa.me/6596963689?text={text}')
    elif call.data == 'visit_website':
        # links to nblgaming.com
        webbrowser.open_new('https://nblgaming.com/')
    await call.answer()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # filename tgbot_status.log
    logger = setup_applevel_logger('tgbot_status')
    app_run()
`
```

and below is the error.

```
`
$ python bot.py
Starting environment...
 Program started successfully
Goodbye!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/telegramBot12345/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 505, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 s
sl:default [Network is unreachable]
`
```

ive tried turning off my firewall to fix the error but im not very well versed in python so not sure if theres something missing in the code or its completely a network issue, for which i also dont know how to fix. ive visited multiple forums to no avail, any help is much appreciated. im using a free account on pythonanywhere btw but this hasnt been an issue before.

Comment: Can you check that you can connect to the website with `curl https://api.telegram.org` from the same environment that you launched the script please?

Comment: @logistic-bot yes it works. ~ $ curl https://api.telegram.org
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: So when your python code tries to connect to the telegram api, it doesn't work, but when you use curl, it does. There must be something different between the two. Also, I think you shouldn't post your bot api token here, make sure to revoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Free accounts can only connect to the internet through the proxy. Check the documentation for the library that you're using to see how to configure it to use a proxy. The details you need are here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/